# Ignore "taking address of temporary" error

Tags: c++, gcc

For this code

```
struct test {};
test f() { return test(); }
void print(test *x) {}
int main()
{
    print(&f());
    print(&test());
}
```

gcc-4.6 emits two "taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]" errors. This was introduced in 4.6, gcc-4.5 could compile it.

The reason is pretty clear and well documented. The problem is that it is a legacy code and, to compile, we **have** to make it work, thus, doing #pragmas around files and/or parts of code to compile them with -fpermissive. Let's say, customers are adamant not to modify the existing **code** (i.e. the fact of calling print() with &f() or &test() cannot be changed, not source files in general). In other words, one way or another this **will** be compiled, the only choice is more or less pain.

So the question is - are there any possible workarounds to make it work without doing -fpermissive in lots of places? -W flags, C++ tricks, etc.

Comment: You can't do "C++ tricks" if you can't change the code, yes? So what *can* you change? Are we just talking compiler flags? How did your customers get it to compile?

Comment: This code can be compiled using MSVC and gcc-4.5. What I can change, I have no particular idea. For example, redefine/overload print() or make it a macro that does local var under gcc-4.6. Any crazy idea (or "dirty hack" if you prefer) is interesting enough.

Comment: There simply is no trick to getting `&test()` to work. You have to change something about the callsite or the return type of `f()` to get around the problem.

Comment: @queen3: That code is invalid, and it is incorrectly accepted by two compilers. Options are simple: correct the code (which will make it compile in all platforms/compilers) or restrict yourself to the broken compilers or other compiler tricks. In any sane situation you should opt for making things right, not forcing the compiler to munch your errors.

Comment: There's _already_ a fix which is putting #pragmas around. Please read the question - one way or another, it _will_ be compiled.

Comment: @queen3: You haven't answered my question: what *can* you change? You said you could put #pragmas, so you *can* change the source code somewhat. So what can be altered?

Comment: What I meant is, the fact of calling print() with &f() or &test() cannot be changed. I.e. to legacy the code should still look the same. #pragmas do not affect legacy code, as well as overloads (which can be global and ifdef-ed).

Comment: Why is compiling with `-fpermissive` not a good solution?

Comment: Command-line -fpermissive hides too many possible errors. So this has to be #pragma push/ignore/pop around each place separately. Too many source code changes.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you've painted yourself into a corner then. There's no way to be selectively `-fpermissive` without annotating the source to indicate where.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "annotating" here but changing source code is OK, as long as the legacy system still sees the same code, which is possible if we put our changes into preprocessor blocks or add new stuff, possibly under ifdefs. -fpermissive is partially done already and it works, but the number of changes is not satisfying. The trick with operator& looks like a solution, the reason that I do not accept that answer is that I'd like to verify it first, tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I meant is, the fact of calling print() with &f() or &test() cannot be changed.

If you have control over the type itself, you can always overload the reference operator, `operator&`, and return `this` from it. It's not a good thing to do in the general case, but it's fairly safe considering that you're returning the correct pointer of the correct type.

If base classes are involved, then it becomes rather more complicated. You'll need to use a virtual operator overload, and each class in the hierarchy will need to implement it separately.

Comment: This will probably break in different cases, like if `test` is a base (suddenly `base::operator&` becomes the best match for `&d` where `d` is of a type derived from `base`... if `test` is aligned with the complete object it will yield a pointer to the correct address but of the different type, if the objects are not aligned then it will return a pointer to the wrong type and addresses)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Noted.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: yes this is a good tip, thanks. We will have to take this into account. But usually these are simple cases like &custom_color_class().

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a workaround by creating an extra `print` overload that will take a `const&`:

```
void print( test const & t ) {
   print(&t);             // Assuming that the function is 'print( test const * )'
                          // a print function should not take a non-const pointer!
}
```

And changing the caller to:

```
print( f() );
```

This requires code changes, but in a very limited form, so it might be acceptable. Also note that

Comment: @NicolBolas: I realized that while rereading my answer and corrected it (well, rather than corrected, I added the assumption that a `print` function should not take a pointer to a mutable object)

Comment: No, I cannot change caller in this way, i.e. it should be &f(), &test().

Comment: @queen3: That is invalid code, and the compiler is right in rejecting it. You should not force the compiler to accept incorrect code, but rather correct the code to be proper.

Comment: Yes, and I do not do it. Customers does.

Comment: @queen3: There is a saying in Spanish (don't take it wrong, I don't mean to offend): *10 Trillion flies cannot be wrong, eat shit!*. The fact that 2 compilers or 10 trillion flies like something does not mean that it is right.

Comment: @queen3 I don't know if you should do it or not but you can overload `&` operator in `test` if you just want to do it anyway : http://ideone.com/rfUGs

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: No, you should not :) Overloading `operator&` is a bad idea ;)

Comment: Mr.Anubis, that is a nice hack! Not sure if it's applicable in all situations, but looks promising.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: This whole thing is a bad idea, you said it yourself... :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just rewrite the code to do exactly what the compiler used to do without complaining? In other words, store your temporary in a temporary (but addressable) variable.

```
struct test {};
test f() { return test(); }
void print(test *x) {}
int main()
{
    test t1 = f();
    test t2 = test();
    print(&t1);
    print(&t2);
}
```

This should behave identically to the way it did with the old compiler version. Tell the customer that the new compiler requires you to change the code to be explicit about something the compiler used to do implicitly.

Comment: See "The problem is that it is a legacy code" in the question.

Comment: Then don't use the new compiler. Either you have to change the code, or you have to use the legacy compiler.

Comment: Or I can use the accepted answer from this question, which I actually already did, and it had worked well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me how much control you have over what, but the following hack seems to work:

**Edit:** Originally had `f` return a reference instead of a copy. DeadMG correctly points out this leads to undefined behavior as soon as the temporary gets used, so restored `f` back to returning a copy.

```
struct test {};
const test & test_copy (const test &t) { return t; }
#define test() test_copy(test())
test f() { return test(); }
#define f() test_copy(f())
void print(const test *) {}
int main()
{
    print(&f());
    print(&test());
}
```

The hack is to basically convert your temporaries into const references, so that the compiler will be happier. It shouldn't be made generally available, it's only purpose is to shut the compiler up. But, it doesn't really solve any underlying problems with the customer code or provided API. You could fix your API, and only resort to the hacks for certain customers:

```
struct test {};
test f() { return test(); }
void print(const test &) {}

#define CUSTOMER_NEEDS_HACK
#ifdef CUSTOMER_NEEDS_HACK
const test & test_copy (const test &t) { return t; }
#define test() test_copy(test())
#define f() test_copy(f())
void print(const test *t) { print(*t); }
#endif
```

Comment: Welcome to undefined behaviour.

Comment: In `f` you return a reference to a temporary. `test_copy` won't be UB in the case of `test()` but could be in other scenarios.

Comment: So you've fixed the UB by ... creating *other* massive problems by abusing a global variable that cannot ever work in a non-trivial actual program. Not sure if improvement.

Comment: @DeadMG: I would like more input on the downvote, so I know what else to improve. Thanks!

Comment: @DeadMG: The only purpose of `test_copy` is to quiet the compiler, which is what the OP had asked. Is that still the reason for the downvote? Thanks

Comment: There is an infinite loop in the macro expansion. Besides other potential issues if it compiled, the fact is that the code will not even compile.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Macro expansions are not recursive. [Proof that it compiles](http://ideone.com/YK9iI). Regards

Comment: @user315052: Interesting, I runned the `cpp` preprocessor and got: `test.cpp:9: error: detected recursion whilst expanding macro "f"`, but if I run the compiler directly (g++/clang++) it does compile...